# Android Emulator Without Internet Connection - Cause: Active VPN on Computer

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, vpn, openvpn

I have a very recurrent problem in my Android Emulator that is whenever i use a vpn (such as FortiClient) on my computer, my emulator internet stops working. I've tried differents approachs but nothing seems to work.
Emulators tested:

- Galaxy Nexus API 29 (no play store)
- Pixel 2 API 30 (have play store)
- 3.2 HGVA slider API 29 (no play store)
  What i've tried:
- Close Emulator & VPN, restart VPN & Emulator (simple)
- Turn off wifi, emu data, and restarted. (simple)
- Cold boot now and/or wiped data from Android Studio.
- Changed emulators, without Google Play services and with
- Added ports 8.8.8.8 to my computer wifi connection, with and without vpn on
- I Have internet permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml (main and debug)

Also i know is nothing to do with my code because i've already tried to use emulator google chrome without running any code and no internet happens :(

But if you're curious, here is some log

```
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'ehnet.laholando.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

Comment: Common VPN disallow local networks while connected to the VPN. Therefore your emulator don't work. VirtualBox based emulators (such as Genymotion) should work if you configure the virtual machine to use networking in "bridged mode". Then the emulator should be able to use your local network (not the VPN).

Comment: Thanks Robert! I will take it into account :)